# Sort NSMutableArray with strings that contain numbers?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray and it has the users high scores saved into it. I want to arrange the items numerically (the numbers are stored in NSStrings.)
Example:
4,2,7,8
To
2,4,7,8
What is the simplest way to do this if the data is stored in NSStrings?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? For NSMutableArray? And for NSString? And for NSComparator? This is really super easy.

Comment: If it is that easy could you answer instead of complaining about it?

Comment: But if he can get you to realize that many answers can be found in the documentation and have you learn how to use it then maybe you look there the next time you have a problem :)

Comment: True... I just didn't feel outgoing that day.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This code will do it:

```
//creating mutable array
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"2", @"7", @"8", nil];

//sorting
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
}];

//logging
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

It uses blocks, make sure your target OS supports that (It's 4.0 for iOS and 10.6 for OSX).

Comment: I get the error `Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'int (^)(struct NSString *, struct NSString *)', expected 'NSComparator'`

Comment: @TheDeveloper I just copy-pasted my code into Xcode, it compiled and worked. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: Is it that your using ARC? I *just* pasted in and built and it gives me that error.

Comment: Ah well, I guess I'll just have so ask the StackOverflow community *again*

Comment: Any idea to sort the array from the bigger number to smaller?

Comment: @user3123201 compare str2 with str1.

Answer (score 1):

This code works. I tried it:

```
NSMutableArray *unsortedHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4", @"2", @"7", @"8", nil];

NSMutableArray *intermediaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *score in unsortedHighScores){
    
    NSNumber *scoreInt = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[score integerValue]];
    [intermediaryArray addObject:scoreInt];
}

NSArray *sortedHighScores = [intermediaryArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedHighScores);
```

The output is this:

> 2
>
> 4
>
> 7
>
> 8

If you have any questions about the code, just ask in the comments. Hope this helps!

Comment: @TheDeveloper You're right. They're NSSNumber objects but it is very easy to convert them back into strings.

Answer (score 1):

The NSMutableArray method [sortUsingSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) should do it:

```
[scoreArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

should do it.

Comment: This will just do a string compare, and does not work well. For e.g. if you have an array with @"10", @"25", @"50", @"51", @"2000" .... running compare will give you: @"10", @"2000", @"25", @"50", @"51". Probably not what you want. @Adam's answer is correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is of nsdictionaries conaining numeric value for key `number`

```
isKeyAscending = isKeyAscending ? NO : YES;

[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {

    NSString *str1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"number"];
    NSString *str2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"number"];

    if(isKeyAscending) { //ascending order
        return [str1 compare:str2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
    } else { //descending order
        return [str2 compare:str1 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
    }
}];

//yourArray is now sorted
```

Comment: `yourArray = [yourArray sortUsingComparator......}];`. We will have to assign resulting output to array, then and then it will print desire output

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874256/sorting-number-using-nssortdescriptor) from [Darshit Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071021/darshit-shah) make it smootly

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"rank"  ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```