# Sorting Number using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios6, nsnumber, nssortdescriptor

I got stuck in another problem again but after a long time.

This time I have database (Core Data), having an attribute of `numbers` which contains integer numbers like 213879,123,4,345,56567 and so.

I need to fetch data in ascending number order similar to like `alphabetically` order.

I am doing this in way given below,

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:
      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"numbers" 
                                    ascending:YES 
                                     selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

but unfortunately it compares only the 1st digit of every number, mean if there are 2 numbers like `123` and `321`, it will compare `1 (first digit of first number)` with `3 (first digit of second number)` and sort them.

It got confuse when there comes `123` and `111` (same first digits of all numbers).

If I am doing something wrong or the SortDescriptor works in this way?
I need the solution to sort the numbers in ascending `123,133,213,451,516` likewise.

**Thing to Remember** 
In actual the attribute `numbers` will contains integer numbers having digits more then 6. e.g `1234567,234568,235481`

Thanks to all who helps me a lot in anticipation.

Comment: First reaction was that you are comparing Strings, but now you said it is NSNumber, i suggest you to re-check by [obj className] it is says NSNumber or NSString

Comment: Please show you data model. If this was a number attribute, it would not be working like this. There is something missing from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your attribute is of type `NSString`. Make sure you make it to `NSNumber`, the sorting will then work as expected.

There is no need to `selector:@selector(compare:)` in your sort descriptor as this is the default anyway.

Comment: Thanks for replaying soon. The attribute is of type `NSNumber`.

Comment: Please amend you question to: (1) show an example of an undesired sorting result and (2) the code you use to store the value of the attribute.

Comment: :: Thanks buddy, it worked fine. There was actually a little mistake in my `Numbers` having some wrong numbers that were causing the problem. I fixed the numbers and applied your solution and it worked very fine for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"rank"  ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Comment: +1, `localizedStandardCompare` works good for numbers sorting using NSSortDescriptor in NSArray.

Comment: I dont understand why but I have an objects with property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *price;` and i got set this property with (i.e.) object.price = @(5727). And if i check `if ([[object price] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])` - this is true.

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"
                              ascending:YES
                             comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*)obj2
                            options:NSNumericSearch];
 }];
```

this is working fine for me 
perfect

Comment: Problem is when you have SQLite store you cannot use comparator in NSSortDescriptor...